# Adding armv7s compiler directive

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, iphone-5

I want to omit some code when compiling my app to armv7s.

I know that when compiling to armv7, the flag `_ARM_ARCH_7` is defined so I can do the following:

```
#ifdef _ARM_ARCH_7
// armv 7 code
#else
// ...
#endif
```

What is the the flag for armv7s? 
Is it `_ARM_ARCH_7S` ?

Comment: This information is still under NDA. Discuss it at devforums.apple.com instead.